# How to play GTA V just to mess around without losing money at the end?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have a guest coming over too and rather than lose money, we just want to go around shooting people and gaining stars… what would you recommend?

Thanks community!

Comment: Backup your save game, then restore it once you're done? As for "how" to do it, that depends on which platform you're playing on.

Comment: I’m playing on ps5. I thought you could have different profiles or activate a cheat code to a “fun” mode or something …. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use a different profile, but then you'd have to start from the prologue and finish the first mission as Franklin before the game lets you have your fun. I don't know if GTA 5 has cheats, though, and unfortunately, I don't have a PS5, so I can't give an answer on how to backup/restore the save file.

Comment: GTA V definitely has [cheats](https://www.gamesradar.com/gta-5-cheats/).

Comment: Check out director mode. I'm not exactly sure how to get to it, but it should be in the interactions menu.